# Cannot access a disposed object in DelegatingHandler class for a HttpClient

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I am using TokenHttpHandler for a HttpClient. That looks like this.

```
public class TokenHttpHandler : DelegatingHandler
  {
    private readonly ITokenCache tokenCache;
    private readonly IHttpProxyClientService proxyClientService;

    public TokenHttpHandler(IHttpProxyClientService proxyClientService, ITokenCache tokenCache)
    {
      this.proxyClientService = proxyClientService;
      this.tokenCache = tokenCache;

      var useProxy = AppSettingsProvider.AppSettings.Proxy.UseProxy;
      InnerHandler = useProxy ? proxyClientService.GetProxyHandler() : new HttpClientHandler();
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
      var response = await SetAuthHeaderAndSendAsync(request, cancellationToken, false).ConfigureAwait(false);
      if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
      {
        response = await SetAuthHeaderAndSendAsync(request, cancellationToken, true);
      }
      return response;
    }

    private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SetAuthHeaderAndSendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, bool forceTokenRefresh)
    {      
      request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", await tokenCache.GetAccessToken(forceTokenRefresh).ConfigureAwait(false));
      return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
  }
```

In ASP.NET core application using autofac I registered the types like that:

```
// Token cache
      builder.RegisterType<TokenCache>().As<ITokenCache>()
        .WithParameter("scope", "Scope")
        .SingleInstance();

      builder.RegisterType<TokenHttpHandler>()
        .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

      builder.RegisterType<ProductionHttpClient>()
        .As<HttpClient>()
        .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

The problem is that as only the code hits the line:

return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

I get error:

"Cannot access a disposed object.\r\nObject name: 'TokenHttpHandler'."
What is going on here?

What am I missing here?

Comment: Hi John, where you able to resolve this ?

Comment: As far as I remember I called async method and forgot to wait for it to finish its work.